# Does calling .toArray() on an ICollection that is an Array return the reference or a copy?

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, extension-methods

I am working on a few extension methods where I need to transform the input collection into an Array.
I want to save memory so I only want to create a copy of the input if it is absolutely necessary.

Do I have to do:

```
 public static ICollection<TSource> ExtMethod<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> predicate)
    {
        TSource[] converted;
        if (source is TSource[])
        {
            converted = source as TSource[];
        }
        else {
            converted = source.ToArray();
        }

    }
```

Or does toArray do the check under the hood and I have exactly the same effect if I do:

```
  public static ICollection<TSource> ExtMethod<TSource>(this ICollection<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> predicate)
    {
        TSource[] converted = source.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it really easy to check?

Comment: Here's the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,783a052330e7d48d,references Click on `Buffer` and on `ToArray` to see what happens in the constructor and on the final ToArray to see what happens there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ToArray` *always* creates a copy. Your extension method does *not* behave the same way.

Note that there are subtleties here around types as well. Consider this code:

```
string[] x = { "a", "b" };
object[] y = x.ExtMethod<object>();
object[] z = x.ToArray<object>();
```

Now the execution-time type of `y` is `string[]` because it's returned the original array - but the execution-time type of `z` is `object[]` because it's created a new array *with the type argument specified*.